# Does Visual Studio 2017 fully support N4266 with the [[deprecated]] attribute?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I'm currently investigating the new features of C++17. I stumbled upon the feature [N4266](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4266.html), which states that now enums and namespaces can also use attributes. Different sources say that Visual Studio 2017 already fully supports this feature. I wrote a test with the [[deprecated]] attribute. For namespaces, this works very well. However, no warning is generated for enums. Is there a mistake in my implementation? Did I miss something?

```
enum MyEnum
{
    val = 0,
    vaal[[deprecated]] = val
};

void test()
{
    MyEnum e  = MyEnum::vaal; //Should emit Warning, but does not
    MyEnum e2 = MyEnum::val;  //No Warning
}
```

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.3.5. [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp17) states that it should be supported since VS2015 already. /std:c++17 is used.

[And this](http://www.bfilipek.com/2017/01/cpp17features.html#attributes-for-namespaces-and-enumerators) also says that this *should* be the correct syntax.

There is no difference if I use enum or enum class.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance

Comment: @Mgetz That also states that it should be supported.

Comment: On GCC I do get compiler warnings for deprecation. On MSVC, I do not. So I think it's safe to rule out anything being wrong with the code snippet.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp-conformance-improvements-2017 may also be useful

Comment: It has to support it at least to some extent or it wouldn't compile due to syntax errors. For example, it won't compile on the 2013 toolset.

Comment: @Mark Afaik thats not correct since C++14. Unknown attributes are no errors, just warnings. If I try [[deprecatedfsfd]] instead, the compiler just says that it does not know that attribute but compiles it just fine. EDIT: Of course that means that the toolset of 2013 could throw an error.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher On 2017, that would give a single warning C5030. On 2013, with the correct spelling, there are several *errors*: syntax errors, C3409, and C2337.

Comment: [They are aware of it](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/47483/visual-c-no-warning-on-temporary-and-unused-deprec.html).  Judging from Larry Hu's response, this is not on the top of the //todo list yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not entirely.

I would say this is a current limitation/bug in MSVC2017 that is possibly worth filing a bug report for, even if the attribute is recognised also in the enumerator case (and doesn't prompt a C5030 warning; as mentioned by Mark in the comments to you question).

Addendum: which has now been verified (as a previously known bug) by a link supplied by Hans Passant:

- [Visual C++: No warning on temporary and unused `[[deprecated]]` variables](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/47483/visual-c-no-warning-on-temporary-and-unused-deprec.html)

---

The C++17 (working draft) standard, [[decl.attr.deprecated]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.attr.deprecated), states:

> §1 The attribute-token `deprecated` can be used to mark names and
>   entities whose use is still allowed, but is discouraged for some
>   reason.
>
> §3 The attribute may be applied to the declaration of a class, a
>   typedef-name, a variable, a non-static data member, a function, a
>   namespace, an enumeration, **an enumerator**, or a template
>   specialization. ...

Using the `/std:c++17` flag when compiling with MSVC2017, the `deprecated` attribute works for all the above but the enumerator:

```
// a class
class [[deprecated]] MyClass {};

// a typedef-name / type alias
[[deprecated]] typedef int MyInt;
using MyFloat [[deprecated]] = float;

// a variable (see main)

// a non-static data member
struct DataMember
{
    int b [[deprecated]];
};

// a function
[[deprecated]]
void myFunction() {}

// a namespace
namespace [[deprecated]] my_namespace
{
    typedef double MyDouble;
}

// an enumeration
enum [[deprecated]] MyEnum {};

// an enumeration
enum MyNewEnum
{
    val[[deprecated]] = 42
};

// a template specialization
template <typename T>
void myTemplateFunction(const T) {} 

template<>
[[deprecated]]
void myTemplateFunction<int>(const int) {}

int main()
{
    MyClass m; // warning C4996: 'MyClass': was declared deprecated
    MyInt i;   // warning C4996: 'MyInt': was declared deprecated
    MyFloat f; // warning C4996: 'MyInt': was declared deprecated
    int j [[deprecated]];
    j = 1;     // warning C4996: 'j': was declared deprecated
    DataMember dm;
    dm.b = 1;  // warning C4996: 'DataMember::b': was declared deprecated
    myFunction();
               // warning C4996: 'myFunction': was declared deprecated
    my_namespace::MyDouble d; 
               // warning C4996: 'my_namespace': was declared deprecated
    MyEnum e;  // warning C4996: 'MyEnum': was declared deprecated
    myTemplateFunction(2);
               // warning C4996: 'myTemplateFunction': was declared deprecated

    MyNewEnum ne = val; // ... no warning

    return 0;
}
```

Both gcc and clang invokes deprecation warnings for `MyNewEnum ne = val;` above, for `-std=c++14` as well as `-std=c++1z`.

On a related note, peculiarly [cppreference's description of the `deprecated` attribute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) seems not to have been updated with N4266, not including "an enumerator" and "a namespace" in the valid use case declarations; even though these are both present in the [C++14 standard draft (7.6.5/2)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf). This could possibly be an indicator that this is a rarely-used feature (applied to enumerators/namespaces) which could explain why it's been (partly) missed in MVCS.

- **Edit:** added a note about this, and it has since been corrected.

#### Some ambiguity in the official MVSC documentation

Finally, the [attributes section in the MSVC docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/attributes2) doesn't really dwell any deeper into specifying for which kinds of declarations the `deprecated` attribute is allowed; showing only an example of deprecating a function declaration.

Although, as you've pointed out (however via link to cppreference rather than MSVC's own docs), [MSVS2015 does explicitly state conformance to N4266](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance), at least for C++17.

> #### Compiler Features
>
> **C++17 Core Language Features**
>
> N4266 Attributes for namespaces and enumerators
>
> Supported: VS2015

However, [Support For C++11/14/17 Features (Modern C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) states the opposite (for VS2015):

> #### Compiler Features
>
> **C++17 Proposed Core Language Features**
>
> N4266 Attributes for namespaces and enumerators
>
> Supported VS2013: No
>
> Supported VS2015: No